# Invalid type: DescribeLayoutResult in salesforce apex class

Tags: apex, developer-console

Below is the apex method and I want to set layoutResult as type DescribeLayoutResult but problem occurs saying ' Invalid type: DescribeLayoutResult '. Apex is in latest version.

```
public static void describeObjectLayout() {
        String objectApiName = 'JSON_Data__c';
        String layoutName = 'Standard Layout';

        DescribeLayoutResult layoutResult = Schema.describeLayout(objectApiName, layoutName, null);
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK this is only available with the type you mention via the SOAP API Which is not available in Apex. You should try to retrieve them via the [built-in Apex Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_Metadata.htm).

Answer (score 2):

There is this Apex [Retrieving and Deploying Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_retrieve_deploy.htm) API that allows [layouts to be handled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Metadata_Layout.htm). But it is an uglier API than the describe ones being based on a generic container that then requires casts to reference specific types e.g.:

```
            List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(
                Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, 
                new String[]{'Lead-Lead Layout'}
            );
            leadLayout = (Metadata.Layout) components.get(0);
```

from [Using to Apex Metadata API to recreate Standard Layouts](https://medium.com/@charlie_77818/using-to-apex-metadata-api-to-recreate-standard-layouts-9ab1de200640).

Note that manipulating this sort of metadata from Apex is not normally necessary given tools like `sfdx` handle this well.